# Regarding 'for' used in the context of time

Tags: word-usage

Is the following ambiguous?

> He has not lived in Boston for 2 years.

Could it mean:

1. It is not true that he has lived in Boston for two years. He might have 
   been living in Boston for only one year.
2. It has been the case for two years that he has not lived in Boston.

Now consider the following. Are they ambiguous?

1. He has not lived in Boston for ages.
2. He has not lived in Boston for ages yet.

Comment: In "He has not lived in Boston for 2 years", my interpretation is that he had been living in Boston in the past but moved out 2 years ago. In the second case, "He has not lived in Boston for ages *yet*", here *yet* doesn't fit very well in the sentence and is not the same meaning as "He has not lived in Boston for ages"

Answer (score 1):

With the kind of ambiguity inherent in a construction like *"He has not lived in Boston for 2 years"*, context is everything. For example:

> "After graduating from Harvard, Fred went to work for a Wall Street hedge fund. He hasn't lived in Boston for 2 years"

means that a minimum of two years has elapsed since Fred lived in Boston. On the other hand,

> "The co-op has rejected Fred's application for an apartment. He hasn't lived in Boston for 2 years"

means that Fred's period of residence in the city falls short of the two years required by the co-op for his application to be considered.

Comment: While I agree with how the first example can be interpreted, you didn't answer the OP's question regarding "He has not lived in Boston for ages (yet)"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That's because I've never heard anybody say anything like that, so it is of no interest to me.

Answer (score 0):

> *"He has not lived in Boston for 2 years."*

I read that exactly as it is - one who has not lived in Boston for 2 years. Perhaps, 2 years ago, he lived in Boston, but has subsequently relocated.

I don't read it as one who currently lives in Boston and has done so for less than two years.

> *"He has not lived in Boston for ages yet"*

Is ambiguous and poorly worded.

> *"He has not lived in Boston for ages"*

is grammatically correct and is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean both things to me, absent context. However, I can't see how it would come up outside of a clear context. And I would assume the second meaning.

It should be clear from the discussion whether current or past Boston residency status is important... and having spent a certain amount of time in Boston is hardly applicable to anything. Unless it relates to some odd bi laws, or argument about who knows better about how to avoid game day traffic at the Fenway.